# How to remove values from an array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a really basic day booking system and need to return all dates within a range, and then remove selected dates from that range. I tried the following code but realised that will remove duplicates which is fine, but I also need that date to be removed too.

Can anyone suggest a good way of doing this?

In the below example I am just hoping to see:

2022-04-03T00:00:00.000000Z

2022-04-04T00:00:00.000000Z

2022-04-05T00:00:00.000000Z

```
$start_date = "2022-04-01";
$end_date = "2022-04-05";

$datesToRemove = [
   '2022-04-01T00:00:00.000000Z',
   '2022-04-02T00:00:00.000000Z'
];

$range = Carbon::parse($start_date)->toPeriod($end_date)->toArray();
$available = array_unique(array_merge($range, $datesToRemove));
return $available;
```

Comment: You would want to use the `array_diff` function instead of `array_merge` and `array_unique`

Comment: `$available = array_diff($range, $datesToRemove);`

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly If I add my range to an array manually but doesn't seem to be working if I use the carbon parse range. Do you happy to have any idea on that?

Comment: @PaoloResteghini I wrote a answer because it was to much for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare it is necessary to have the compared values in the same format. I decide to morph the $datesToRemove to Carbon format. The you can use to nested loops and check with PHP `in_array()` function.

```php
$start_date = "2022-04-01";
$end_date = "2022-04-05";

$datesToRemove = [
"2022-04-01T00:00:00.000000Z",
"2022-04-02T00:00:00.000000Z"
];

$range = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($start_date)->toPeriod($end_date)->toArray();
$datesToRemove2 = [];
foreach($datesToRemove as $r) {
    $datesToRemove2[] = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($r);
}

$res = [];
foreach($datesToRemove2 as $index => $d1) {
    if(in_array($d1, $range)) {        
        unset($range[$index]);        
    }
}

return $range;
```

**output**

```
{
  "2":"2022-04-03T00:00:00.000000Z",
  "3":"2022-04-04T00:00:00.000000Z",
  "4":"2022-04-05T00:00:00.000000Z"
}
```

Means that